# Data structure in C# for multiple properties without creating a class

Tags: c#, oop, data-structures

I need a data structure in C# that can hold 2 things:-

1. Resource File Path
2. Resource File Language

After that i need to iterate over a list of such structure.

Is creating a class like below the only option?

```
public class ResourceFile
    {
        public string FilePath { get; set; }

        public string Language { get; set; }
    }
```

And then creating a list as following:

```
var list = new List<ResourceFile>()
```

I don't want to create an additional class file in project for this minor requirement.

Other options that I considered but not sure if they are right:-

1. Dictionary

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>>
```

But the key and value are not related in typical key value pair relationship. 
In this case, Path can't be a key to language.

2. Tuple

```
List<Tuple<string, string>>
```

This is probably the closest to fulfilling my requirement. 
However since i have never used Tuples before, not sure if my use case is valid for using Tuples.

So here i can have a list of Tuples. 
Each tuple will hold 2 values. First value will be path and second one will be language.

Any other options?

Comment: Using a `Tuple` or a `ValueType` is probably the best choice unless you want to define a custom type. Why do you need yet another option?

Comment: Why not create an appropriate data structure?  Using an appropriate structure will make everything easier later on.

Comment: This may be a better fit on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). But asside this, why do you not want to make an own class or structure for this. It seams like this is something that should be included in your Object-Model.

Comment: "*I don't want to create an additional class file in project for this minor requirement."* why not ? Code will become easier to read.

Comment: Also you may don't know that you can define multiple classes in one file so you don't need to create an additional _file_

Comment: *Why* this question? What *is* the requirement? It's impossible to give an answer without knowing what prevents the use of a class or struct. Why not an ExpandoObject for example? Or a Dictionary? Or just a string containing JSON?

Comment: @Ackdari i already have a model class file created, which is being used to Deserialize Json file.
This is another reason i dont want to create a new class, as ResourceFile was the most suitable name which has already been taken by my model class file.

Comment: You should bite the bullet and create a simple class for this. It will make the code clearer, more robust and easier to use. You can also then validate the filename and language strings (e.g. for not being null or blank) in the class constructor, and ensure that users of the class never need to worry about the properties being null or blank, for example.

Comment: @Akshunya and why isn't it an option that you use the already defined class?

Comment: @Akshunya nothing prevents you from creating another class. Or just using the JObject or JArray returned by the deserializer.

Comment: A dictionary is fine.  You have a unique key which is the path.  Often a dictionary will have a unique key and value which has multiple properties like an instance of a class.

Comment: If you don't want a class (a reference type), you could use a struct (a value type). You'd need to think about use cases to decide which is the best fit. Creating a class or struct is pretty simple - I find your rationale perplexing

Comment: @Ackdari That existing model class file has different set of properties, as compared to my current use case.

Comment: @jdweng a dict as implemented above might not be fine if the ResourceList will relate 1 path to >1 languages, though. Though, in that case OP could use `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` where key is path and value is list of associated languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With c# > 7.0 you can use tuples syntax like this:

```
var files = new List<(string FilePath, string FileLanguage)>();
files.Add((FilePath: "path", FileLanguage: "lang"));
Console.WriteLine($"File 0 -  PATH: {files[0].FilePath}, LANG: {files[0].FileLanguage}");
```

It acts like a ValueTuples but here you can have more than only two elements and each element can be named.

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/tuples

Answer (score 1):

Your list of tuples idea is a good option if you don't want to create a new class.
Tuples are data structures that simply help group information without forcing the key, value structure as you mentioned.

The one thing you should keep in mind when using tuples is that they are immutable - meaning you can't add, remove, swap, etc. elements inside the tuple once assigned.  A List however is mutable, so you could add or remove tuples from the list.

Comment: The other thing to keep in mind with using tuples -- not so much the new value tuples, but old fashioned `Tuple<T1, T2>` -- is that the properties are named `Item1` and `Item2`, which is an aggressive act of wanton self-sabotage. `Item1` is not a descriptive name. If you're going to recommend tuples, please be clear that you mean value tuples, and at least point folks in the right direction to learn the feature. The old ones were a mistake.

Comment: ^- Definitely. After 6 monthes without opening the code, what is `MyFileResource.Item1` ? The file path ? The language ? What should contain the file resource ?

Comment: As Ed mentioned, I should clarify that I mean ValueTuples. These have the option for naming the elements within them. From documentation here's an example: var named = (first: "one", second: "two");

Comment: You should clarify that *in your answer*. It does nobody any good to add a comment saying "yeah, that feature I explicitly mentioned, I meant a different one with a similar name". Szymon's answer does a solid job.